# $resource angular returning undefined with $promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been stuck on this for quite a while now and cannot figure out why the value is not being returned. I am using Angular `$resource` to make a GET request to an API.

My $resource factory looks like this:

```
.factory("Bookings", function ($resource) {
    return $resource("www.example/bookings_on_date/:day", {});
})
```

I have tried to implement promises but am unable to do so correctly.

```
function getBookings(day){
        return Bookings.get({"day": day}).$promise.then(function(data) {
        console.log(data.total)
        return data.total;
    });
}

$scope.todaysBookings = getBookings(TODAY);
$scope.tomorrowsBookings = getBookings(TOMORROW);
```

When I view either `console.log($scope.todaysBookings)` or `$scope.tomorrowBookings` in the console it returns undefined.

I have also tried everything from this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsengel/aogu66fj/) but unfortunately have not had any luck.

Comment: You're missing a `return` before `Bookings.get`. JavaScript functions with no return value return `undefined`.

Comment: You need to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/16825593

Comment: Ping me and let me know if it solved your issue so we can close as duplicate, or if it didn't - edit and we'll see what we can do about it - happy coding.

Comment: Like you just did, by writing `@` in front of my name - were you able to solve your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be like this:

```
function getBookings(day) {
    return Bookings.get({"day": day}).$promise.then(function(data) {
        return data.total;
    });
}

getBookings(TODAY).then(function(total) {
    $scope.todaysBookings = total;
});

getBookings(TOMORROW).then(function(total) {
    $scope.tomorrowsBookings = total;
});
```

**Update:** I think next code style could help you to prevent next *extending method* problems:

```
function getBookings(args) {
    return Bookings.get(args).$promise;
}

getBookings({"day": TODAY}).then(function(data) {
    $scope.todaysBookings = data.total;
});

getBookings({"day": TOMORROW}).then(function(data) {
    $scope.tomorrowsBookings = data.total;
});
```

A little advantages here:

- Pass object into function could help you easily pass different
  arguments into method and arguments are very close to method call (a
  little bit easy to read);
- Return complete response from function
  could help you to process different data (method could replay
  different response depends on arguments, but it's not good practise
  in this case);

**p.s.** Otherwise, you could remove function declaration and code like this (to keep it as simple, as possible):

```
Bookings.get({"day": TODAY}).$promise.then(function(data) {
    $scope.todaysBookings = data.total;
});

Bookings.get({"day": TOMORROW}).$promise.then(function(data) {
    $scope.tomorrowsBookings = data.total;
});
```